# How to add multiple objects created from form input, to a list in react

Tags: reactjs, list, loops

I have a form, that is filled in for 18 holes on a golf course, each of the holes has the following fields, `hole`, `par`, `stroke`, `yards`, `courseid`

As each input field is filled in, it fires onChange and sets the value of a variable in form state, to the input fields value.

In my form object I have all these fields,

```
const [form, setForm] = useState([
    {
        hole1: 1,
        par1: '',
        stroke1: '',
        yards1: ''
    },
    {
        hole2: 2,
        par2: '',
        stroke2: '',
        yards2: ''
    },
    {
        hole3: 3,
        par3: '',
        stroke3: '',
        yards3: ''
    },

   //repeated for 18 holes
```

When completed and submit is clicked, it fires the save function, A list is sent to the backend (SpringBoot) to be saved in dB.

As there are 18 holes, I need to loop over the data so that I can fill in 18 objects to put into the list to send to the backend.

I have made a `holes` object

```
   let[holes, setHoles] = useState({
        "hole": '',
        "par": '',
        "stroke": '',
        "yards": '',
        "course": {
            "courseid": ''
        }
    });
```

which I now want to populate with the values from the `form` data.

so I want to set the `holes` values for each field to that for,

```
form.hole1,
form.par1,
form.stroke1,
form.yards1
```

Then add that `holes` object to the list, then run the loop again and add all the values for hole 2, etc etc until all 18 holes are done.

When using a loop like,

```
for (let i= 1; i< 19; i++) {
            holes = {
                "hole": index,
                "par": form.par,
                "stroke": form.stroke,
                "yards": form.yards,
                "course": {
                    "courseid": 3
                }
            }
            const newList = list.concat({holes})
            list = newList;
        };
```

how is it best to tell it to take `form.par1` on the first loop, then `form.par2` on the second loop etc.

I feel like I need two loops running here, so that it starts off looping through all the numbers 1-18, and before moving to the next number it loops through the objects in the form,

so it starts at hole 1, get the `holes` object, gets the value from the first `form object, sets the 4 fields in` hole`to those in the first`form object i.e par1, yards1 etc, then concats the `hole` object to the `list` then moves on to the number 2 and continues this till all 18 are complete, but I am not sure how I can achieve this.

Comment: The design/explanation here is a bit confusing, but I think what you are looking for is string interpolation in your object properties. You can do `"par": form[\`par${i}\`],` to construct the property name that you need.

Comment: Great thanks, it took me ages to write that question out as it's hard to explain what I wanted. I tried loads of ways of appending the value of i in the loop to par, but couldn't get it to work. I will try this tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the `form` array shaped as you've described, you can map this to the desired `list` of holes like so:

```js
const list = form.map((hole, i) => {
  const num = i + 1;
  return {
    hole: num,
    par: hole[`par${num}`],
    stroke: hole[`stroke${num}`],
    yards: hole[`yards${num}`],
    course: {
      courseid: 3,
    },
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great. But has now shown another issue, but I will open a new question for that.